# SQLite - sorting question

Tags: sqlite

I am using the following query to display database rows in an alphabetical order:

```
SELECT word_id FROM table1 ORDER BY word ASC
```

But I want to get values from table2, where I don't have column "word" and to sort it by column "word" which is in table1.

I want something like this:

```
SELECT word_id FROM table2 ORDER BY table1.word ASC
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's something called "JOIN" ... enjoy reading about it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must connect the two tables with a join:

```
SELECT t2.word_id
FROM table2 t2
   , table1 t1
WHERE t2.word_id = t1.word_id  -- this is the join
ORDER BY t1.word ASC
```